# how to track each keyhit in EditText android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I need to track each character that the user types in the `EditText`.

Is there any way to do that ?

Currently I have an `EditText` and I need an image to be displayed when user enters the first character.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [`EditText#addTextChangedListener(TextWatcher watcher)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your purpose you can use `text watcher`

```
et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```